# How to rewrite a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, impala

Please, consider the following query:

```
create table lt (id1 int, val1 string);
insert into lt VALUES  (1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three");
create table rt (id2 int, val2 string);
insert into rt VALUES  (2, "two"), (3, "three"), (4, "four");

select * from lt left join rt on id1=id2;

+-----+-------+------+-------+
| id1 | val1  | id2  | val2  |
+-----+-------+------+-------+
| 1   | one   | NULL | NULL  |
| 2   | two   | 2    | two   |
| 3   | three | 3    | three |
+-----+-------+------+-------+
```

For this specific example I can rewrite the LEFT JOIN as INNER JOIN + query that gets all IDs that are not in the "rt" table:

```
select lt.*, NULL as id2, NULL as val2 from lt where id1 not in (select id2 from rt) 
union all
select * from lt join rt on id1=id2;
+-----+-------+------+-------+
| id1 | val1  | id2  | val2  |
+-----+-------+------+-------+
| 1   | one   | NULL | NULL  |
| 2   | two   | 2    | two   |
| 3   | three | 3    | three |
+-----+-------+------+-------+
```

Both querires give same result for this example. But is this generally true? Can I rewrite **any** LEFT JOIN in this fashion (or may be there is a shorter way)?

Comment: iam not even sure what results you are expecting see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also which RDMS are you using as the tag is sql which is about valid ANSI/ISO SQL standards `create table lt (id1 int, val1 string)` is not valid as there is no `string` datatype in the standards.

Comment: Not sure if this is your ask. I've added the results I'm seeing when executing both queries. My RDBMS is Impala (distributed MMPP), but the quuestion is on a LEFT JOIN in general. Am I able to rewrite any LEFT JOIN with other SQL constructs?

Comment: *"but the quuestion is on a LEFT JOIN in general. Am I able to rewrite any LEFT JOIN with other SQL constructs?"*  Now i understand what you are asking, but a rewrite might not always be faster i would check your SQL with a query plan and indexes and some more test data

Comment: the not exists in the other table is generally solved by LEFT JOIN, NOT IN or using a co-related subquery with NOT EXISTS

Comment: There are cases/issues when I cannot use LEFT JOIN at all with Impala. I'm trying to get a working workaround that would not use LEFT JOIN but preserve the same logic

Comment: You can trivially write a `LEFT JOIN` using a `FULL JOIN`.  I don't see the point of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b6dd33c1c393aea770ade6aa1376710)**

```
select val1, NULL as id2, NULL as val2 from lt where id1 not in (select id2 from 
rt) 
union 
select val1,id1, val1 from lt where 1=1 and id1 in (select id2 from rt)
```

OUTPUT:

```
val1    id2 val2
one     
two     2   two
three   3   three
```

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of a LEFT JOIN in my query

Comment: `where 1=1` i assume this is from the SQL optimizers dark days time? As it does nothing as it is always 1 or true